# Find Max and Min in an array type struct

Tags: c++, for-loop, struct, max

I am trying to find max, min , mean and average of an array type struct. I have a function "bsort" that sorts all my data using bubble sort in struct teams, which I call it here to sort my data fisrt. here is the code I am using to find the max:

```
void bfind(struct annual_stats *stats, int y, int year, string field, string item){ 
    bsort(stats, y, year, field, "increasing"); 

    if (item == "max"){
        int max;
     for (int i = 0; i < NO_TEAMS; i++) {

    if (stats->teams->games[i] > max){
            max = stats->teams->games[i];
         }
    }
}
```

}

where stats is a struct that has two elements, an integer and another struct:

```
struct annual_stats{
int year;
struct team_stats teams[ NO_TEAMS ];
};
```

Then I have these declarations:

```
#define NO_TEAMS      32 // Number of NFL teams
#define TEAM_NAME_LEN 25 // Maximum team name string length
#define TOP_LEN        6 // Maximum time of possession string length
```

and my struct teams is as follow:

```
 struct team_stats{
char team_name[ TEAM_NAME_LEN ]; // Name of NFL team
int games; // Number of games played in the season
float pts_per_game; // Points per game
int total_points; // Total points
int scrimmage_plays; // Scrimmage plays
float yds_per_game; // Yards per game
float yds_per_play; // Yards per play
float first_per_game; // First downs per game
int third_md; // Third down conversions
int third_att; // Third down attempts
int third_pct; // Third down percentage
int fourth_md; // Fourth down conversions
int fourth_att; // Fourth down attempts
int fourth_pct; // Fourth down percentage
int penalties; // Number of penalties
int pen_yds; // Penalty yards
char top_per_game[ TOP_LEN ]; // Time of possession per game
int fum; // Number of fumbles
int lost; // Fumbles lost
int to; // Turnover ratio
};
```

and then teams is an array type struct which holds 20 elements in type int, float, and char.
what I am trying to do here is that I want to find the max on games, which is an int member of teams. When I run this program I keep getting an error that invalid types int[int] for array subscript.
I know if I remove [], my program compiles, but I think that I have to specify the element [i]?
Can anyone please give me some hints?

My program is reading the data from a text files.

BTW, I am not a pro in C++, so please explain in the simplest possible way! 
Thanks.

Comment: For your real question: Please post  a [mcve] so we can diagnose the problem.

Comment: please short down your question and share "bsort" function with us. and also is NO_TEAMS declared somewhere?, its best to be accurate in your questioning here since it will be good for us in helping you. cheers :)

Comment: Meta comment: Do you actually *have* to do this C-array/pointer/self-made sort business? The task you mention in the first sentence can be done much more efficient and trivially with the standard library.

Comment: @DanyalImran We probably do not need to see `bsort` to diagnose a compiler error in `bfind`, don't you think?

Comment: Well, this is a very long program, and that is why I tried to keep it short. Yes, NO-TEAM has been declared on the top of the code. I am going to add some codes to the question.

Comment: @BaummitAugen You are absolutely correct, but i am just trying to trace if something wrong went with the flow that cause something to unintentionally change in bfind function.

Comment: `team_stats::games` is a simple integer, so which "elements" are you trying to access with `games[i]`?

Comment: @DanyalImran bsort function is working fine since it has been tested and verified before I start working on bfind.

Comment: "Well, this is a very long program, and that is why I tried to keep it short" - still you can post a short program that shows your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void bfind(struct annual_stats *stats, int y, int year, string field, string item){ 
    bsort(stats, y, year, field, "increasing"); 

    if (item == "max"){
        int max;
     for (int i = 0; i < NO_TEAMS; i++) {

    if (stats->teams[i].games > max){
            max = stats->teams[i].games;
         }
    }
}
```

I think it should `stats->teams[i].games`

Comment: @BaummitAugen you are right. It has to be teams[i].games. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I've just try it, and yeah @BaummitAugen right, it shou'ld using dot, I'll update my answer

Comment: @malioboro Thank you for your suggestion. It led me to the right track.

Comment: No need for edit messages in the body itself, just edit what needs to be edited.

Comment: oh, thanks, this is my first experience to edit my answer

Comment: @malioboro No problem. For future reference, if you feel like an edit needs extra explanation, provide that in the edit summary while editing. This is especially important for <2k rep users editing other people's posts as those edits need to be approved by the reviewers.